# Google Calendar API access not configured

Tags: android, api, calendar

I've downloaded a sample project from here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-android-sample/?repo=samples

I performed all the steps as described except that retrieved the SHA1 key using the Keytool plugin for Eclipse. When I run the app on my phone however, it shows an Access not configured error message 
The following is from the LogCat:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
 "code": 403,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "usageLimits",
       "message": "Access Not Configured",
       "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
     }
  ],
   "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
```

I have created a project in google console, enabled the calendar APIs, created an OAuth2 Client ID, used the SHA1 key from Eclipse and have not seen any error maessages. I can't see a client secret in the console though. Do you have any idea what is missing?

These are the permissions from the Android Manifest, in case you're wondering.

```
enter code here


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I'm new to using the calendar APIs would like to see this app work before creating my own. Also, I suspect this might become an issue in the future as well.

Comment: Well I managed to solve the problem and sure enough at the core of the issue was not getting the SHA1 key properly. Finally I discovered Keystore Explorer which helped a lot. Somehow I just couldn't get the command prompt keytool to work (even if I managed to log on to the keystore file).

http://www.lazgosoftware.com/kse/index.html

Comment: solved using http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html

Answer (score 1):

Access Configuration needs to be performed using the Client API.  See the links in the left column.

Since you have to specify scope when asking for user authorization, this effort seems redundant.  But necessary nonetheless.  http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm