# calendar-android-sample v1.15.0-rc, API KEY necessary?

Tags: google-api-java-client

When running the calendar-android-sample app I'm getting 'Access Not Configured.'. Assume the API KEY is required, but I'm not seeing where to put the API KEY in the calendar-android-sample source code.  Previously this was set in ClientCredentials.java.  Could someone tell me how to get the calendar-android-sample v1.15.0-rc app to work?

Note: To build the calendar-android-sample I had to get the Extra 'Google Play Services', locate the appropriate jar file (android-sdk-r21/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar), copy it to the calendar-android-sample/libs directory.

Comment: Looks like this question has been asked before, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209710/google-calendar-api-access-not-configured-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863500/google-calendar-api-access-not-configured (there may be more). Did you look into any of those first?

Answer (score 0):

All of the necessary instructions to run any given sample are in the instructions.html file found within that sample. [Here is the instructions file for the calendar-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-android-sample/instructions.html), which should answer your question.

In short, you're going to need to register your application on the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and use your unique package name and signing certificate fingerprint to identify your application.

Unfortunately, the package name has to be GLOBALLY unique, such that yours is the only application registered with that name. Java package naming promotes this by suggesting you use your organization's URL (which you know is unique) but it can be a pain when registering the widely-used sample code at com.google...

Comment: The instructions appear to be off, like where's the Create an OAuth 2.0 Client IDI'm following the instructions, and still getting the error.  Perhaps wait 24 hours?

Comment: Clicking the 'Create another client ID' button, then selecting 'Installed applications' and 'Android', then entering the calendar-android-sample package name and my debug.keystore SHA1 fingerprint.  Rerunning the calendar-android-sample app and still getting 'Access Not Configured'.  Wait 24 hours?

Comment: Did you change the package name from the default? The package name should be unique. The APIs console usually gives an error if you use one already in use. Try changing it to something unique like `com.google.api.services.samples.calendar.android.yournameblah` in the code and the APIs console.

Comment: Tried another package name and it worked!  Like you said it has to be UNIVERSALLY unique.  Happy, Joy!

Comment: @user2387030 Great, happy to hear! I'll update the answer to be more specific- please feel free to mark it as "accepted" if you feel it solved your problem :)